# SecItemAdd returns errSecParam error after including SecAccessControlRef

Tags: ios, objective-c

I wish to implement `kSecAttrAccessControl` into my `SecItemAdd` function but the `SecItemAdd` keeps returning the `errSecParam` error.

Is anyone able to spot the error or is there anything missing in the code below?

```
static NSDictionary * AFKeyChainQueryDictionaryWithIdentifier(NSString *identifier){
    NSCParameterAssert(identifier);
    SecAccessControlRef sacObject = SecAccessControlCreateWithFlags(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                            kSecAttrAccessibleWhenPasscodeSetThisDeviceOnly,
                                            kSecAccessControlUserPresence,
                                            nil);

    return @{
            kSecClass: kSecClassGenericPassword,
            kSecAttrService: @"AFOAuthCredentialService",
            kSecAttrAccount: identifier,
            kSecAttrAccessControl: (__bridge_transfer id)sacObject,
            kSecUseAuthenticationUI: (__bridge_transfer id)kSecUseAuthenticationUIAllow,

    };
}
```

```
+ (BOOL)storeCredential:(AFOAuthCredential *)credential
        withIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier
        withAccessbility:(id)accessbility
{
    //credential contains credential.ValueA and credential.ValueB
    
    
    NSMutableDictionary *queryDictionary = [AFKeychainQueryDictionaryWithIdentifier(identifier) mutableCopy];
    
    NSMutableDictionary *update = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    update[(__bridge id)kSecValueData] = [NSKeyedArchiver archiveDataWithRootObject:credential];
    update[(__bridge id)kSecAttrAccessible] = (__bridge id)kSecAttrAccessibleAlways;
    
    [queryDictionary addEntriesFromDictionary:update];
    
    status = SecItemAdd((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)queryDictionary, NULL);
    
    return status;
}
```

After researching on most of the forums I had tried to implement the suggestions such as removing `kSecAttrAccessible` or directly converting `credential.ValueA` from `NSString` to `NSData`. None of them are worked.

I have tried to remove the `kSecAttrAccessControl` and it is able to create in `SecItemAdd` so the logic seems correct. But `kSecAttrAccessControl` must be included as one of the requirements.